# fastAPI returning content-type 'application/liquid'

Tags: python, shopify, liquid, fastapi, shopify-app

I have a custom search algorithm API for a shopify store. The API perfectly receives calls and processes them. However, I need to return a liquid formatted response for shopify to integrate my response properly to its theme. I'm using fast API to return a response. Does anyone know how I can properly return liquid content to shopify?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In FastAPI you can return a custom response like this:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/search/")
def shopify_search():
    return Response(content="SearchResults", media_type="application/liquid")
```

Source: [the extensive documentation for FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/)